# Visualization of categorical data with too many categories

Tags: data-visualization, categorical-data, many-categories

When dealing with data visualization, is it possible to produce a good graph from a table that has categorical data with too many levels and none of the levels have a reasonable amount of entries count? For example, in 178 lines, I have 124 unique nominal categories, wich only 3 of them have more than 5 entries in the table, and most other categories only one.

Is it possible to have an elegant graph in situations like these? Are there better solutions to summarize and visualize this kind of data?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include a small representative sample of your data, along with an indication of what you want to show in your graph?

Comment: do you absolutely need all 124 categories, or can they be collapsed into larger, more meaningful categories?

Comment: [this site](http://deltarho.org/) specializes in visualzing large and complex data.

Comment: Please add a small representative sample of your data, along with an indication of what you want to show in your graph.